# MEX queries with updates

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array **A** of length **n**(<= 500000).

**A**[**i**] <= 10^9.

There's **q**(<= 50000) queries of 2 types:

1. Given **l** **r** - find the smallest positive integer number which is not presented in A in range [**l**, **r**] - Mex - (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)).
2. Given **i** **x** - change value of **A**[**i**] to **x**.

Naive O(**n**) for query and O(1) for update is too slow - O(**n**^2) in general.

Can you come up with efficient algorithm/data structure to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with segment tree(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) data structure? you can use that to solve this problem. Overall complexity will be O(nlogn).

Comment: I don't understand how to find MEX with segment tree. Can you please describe it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Segment tree** data structure and complexity will be `O(nlogn + qlogn)`.If you are not familiar with [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) than it's better to gather knowledge about it. You will find plenty of resouces about it in online.

In Segment tree generally each node keeps information about a specific range. Normally, leaf node keeps information about specific array index and internal node generates or updates informatin from his left and right child.

Consider these cases for the smallest positive integer number which is not presented in `A` in range `[l, r]`:

1. For {2,3} answer is 1 (1 is the smallest positive integer).
2. for {1,2} answer is 3
3. for {1,4,2} answer is 3

**For the case where answer is 1:**

If minimum value in the range is greater than 1, then answer is 1. For this build a segment to find what is minimum value in this specific range. See figure below:

[image]

As we can see from above figure, leaf node holds the specific array index value and internal node updates it's value from it's left and right child value(`min(left child's min value, right child's min value)`). From this segment we can find minimum value for any range in `O(logn)`. If any array index value changes, we can update the tree in `O(logn)`.

**For the case where answer is (max of the range)+1:**

For this build a segment to find what is maximum value in this specific range. It is similar to above segment tree, instead of finding minimum value we are gonna find maximum value.

**For the case where answer is neither 1 nor (max of the range)+1:**

For this case we will need a segment tree that will give smallest missing positive value that is greater than minimum value of the range `[l,r]` and less than maximum value of the range `[l,r]`.
We will use value `0` to represent there is no missing value for this range `[l,r]`.
For leaf node we will set missing value to `0`. 
Now how we will compute missing value for internal node.
Let's say for a internal node `P` we are gonna calculate the missing value. `P` has left child `L` and right child `R`.
Missing value for `P` will be calculated using following procedure:

```
P.Missing_Value = infinite value
// for the case L = {1,2} , R = {4,5}
if L.Max_Value+1 < R.Min_Value {
  P.Missing_Value = min(P.Missing_Value, L.Max_Value + 1)
}

// for the case L = {4,5} , R = {1,2}
if R.Max_Value+1 < L.Min_Value {
  P.Missing_Value = min(P.Missing_Value, R.Max_Value + 1)
}

// for the case L = {1,3} , R = {1,3,4,5} or L = {1,3} , R = {4,5} or L = {3,5} , R = {1,2}
if L.Missing_Value != 0 && (L.Missing_Value < R.Min_Value || L.Missing_Value > R.Max_Value || L.Missing_Value == R.Missing_Value) {
  P.Missing_Value = min(P.Missing_Value, L.Missing_Value)
}

// for the case R = {1,3} , L = {1,3,4,5} or R = {1,3} , L = {4,5} or R = {3,5} , L = {1,2}
if R.Missing_Value != 0 && (R.Missing_Value < L.Min_Value || R.Missing_Value > L.Max_Value || R.Missing_Value == L.Missing_Value) {
  P.Missing_Value = min(P.Missing_Value, R.Missing_Value)
}

// if there is no missing value
if P.Missing_Value == infinite {
  P.Missing_Value = 0
}
```

[image]

To finalize

1. First check whether ans could be 1.
2. If ans can not be 1, then check missing value.
3. If missing value not found, then ans will max value + 1.

Above tree will be your final segment tree. From this you can query min, max and missing value for any range.  These query and update(if array index value changes) will take `O(logn)`.

Some Tutorial/Resoure about segment tree:

- https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/segment-trees/tutorial/
- https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html

Comment: For L = {1, 2, 3, 5} and R = {1, 2, 5} missing value for P is 4 but your procedure will return 0.

Comment: @aldd can you give me the problem link so that i can test my algo?

Comment: No, I have only statement